# Function call stack: train_function error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a dataset with 565 features and 10 different columns on the prediction site for predicting labels in the training model.Here is the model summary dimensions :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Model: "sequential"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 563, 64)           256
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 36032)             0
_________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                (None, 50)                1801650
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 50)                2550
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 10)                510
=================================================================
Total params: 1,810,066
Trainable params: 1,810,066
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Datatypes of the dataset and null values in each of the column :

```
0      float64
1      float64
2      float64
3      float64
4      float64
        ...
570    float64
571    float64
572    float64
573    float64
574    float64
Length: 575, dtype: object
0      0
1      0
2      0
3      0
4      0
      ..
570    0
571    0
572    0
573    0
574    0
Length: 575, dtype: int64
```

dimensions of the dataset : (41490, 575).The error is showing as follows :

```
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/10
^M  1/332 [..............................] - ETA: 0s - loss: 6.7792 - accuracy: 0.0100 - precision: 0.0112Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallelised_script_realdata2.py", line 68, in <module>
    results = model.fit(train_X,train_y,validation_split = 0.2,epochs=10,batch_size = 100)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 108, in _method_wrapper
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py", line 1098, in fit
    tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 780, in __call__
    result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py", line 807, in _call
    return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 2829, in __call__
    return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1848, in _filtered_call
    cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 1924, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager))
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py", line 550, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/execute.py", line 60, in quick_execute
    inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [predictions must be >= 0] [Condition x >= y did not hold element-wise:] [x (sequential/dense_4/Softmax:0) = ] [[-nan -nan -nan...]...] [y (Cast_6/x:0) = ] [0]
         [[{{node assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/else/_21/assert_greater_equal/Assert/AssertGuard/Assert}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1270]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

Here is the code :

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Conv1D, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import time
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow.keras.metrics

data = pd.read_csv('Step1_reducedfile.csv',skiprows = 1,header = None)
data = data.sample(frac=1).reset_index(drop=True)
data = data.to_numpy()
train_X = data[0:data.shape[0],0:565]
train_y = data[0:data.shape[0],565:data.shape[1]]
train_X = train_X.reshape((train_X.shape[0], train_X.shape[1], 1))
             
import random
neurons = 50
strategy = tensorflow.distribute.MirroredStrategy()
with strategy.scope():
    model = tf.keras.Sequential([
      tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64,kernel_size = 3,activation='relu',input_shape=train_X.shape[1:]),
      tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(neurons,activation='relu'),
      tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'),])
    model.summary()
    sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.05, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.24, nesterov=True)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',optimizer=sgd,metrics=['accuracy',tensorflow.keras.metrics.Precision()])
    
    model.summary()
    results = model.fit(train_X,train_y,validation_split = 0.2,epochs=10,batch_size = 100)
    print(results)
```

Comment: The error suggests that something is wrong in the last layer of your model (dense_4). 
Can you check your labels for 
1) Nan values
2) Values < 0

Comment: Yes,there are values < 0.What should I do ? I cant remove them..

Comment: I substituted negative values with zero(just for trial), but still, the issue persists.

Comment: You are building a classifier that needs labeled data. These values need to be integers => 0. The negative values you have need to be mapped to these integers.
You would also want to remove NaN or null values from your data set.

Comment: Remove the precision metric. Does it work?